# Linking Python classes

Tags: python, class

so I have a tast to link 2 classes together.In my case its classes Radnik(worker in English) and Odsek(department in English),so when I,for example,create a new worker I have to assign him to some department.This is my model class,I made the create worker and department method and it works,but i have no idea how to connect those 2 classes and assign a worker to some department.

```
class Worker(Identification):
    def __init__(self,mark,name, surname,personalNumber,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth,countryOfBirth):
        #super().__init__(oznaka=oznaka)
        self.mark=mark
        self.name=name
        self.surname=surname
        self.personalnumber=personalnumber
        self.dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth
        self.placeOfBirth=placeOfBirth
        self.countryOfBirth=countryOfBirth
        
        
    
       
          
class Department(Identification):
    def __init__(self,mark,name,maxNumberOfWorkers,description):
        self.mark=mark
        self.name=name
        self.maxNumberOfWorkers=maxNumberOfWorkers
        self.description=description
```

Comment: Can you simplify the question, and use English identifiers? I think I know what you are asking, but it's hard to tell without reading Slovenian(?). I suspect much of this code is unnecessary; at least for the purposes of this question, can you get rid of the unnecessary getters and setters and just assume that no one will try to set an attribute to an incorrect value?

Comment: So when I try to create a worker,besides the mark,name,surname... i need to choose a department aswell,we were told to link the classes but i have no idea how to do it....

Comment: Is the department class supposed to keep a list of workers assigned to the department, or is the worker supposed to keep a reference to the department it belongs to, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
class Worker():
    def __init__(self,mark,name, surname,personalNumber,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth,countryOfBirth, Department):
        #super().__init__(oznaka=oznaka)
        self.mark=mark
        self.name=name
        self.surname=surname
        self.personalnumber=personalNumber
        self.dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth
        self.placeOfBirth=placeOfBirth
        self.countryOfBirth=countryOfBirth
        self.Department = Department
        
              
class Department():
    def __init__(self,mark,name,maxNumberOfWorkers,description):
        self.mark=mark
        self.name=name
        self.maxNumberOfWorkers=maxNumberOfWorkers
        self.description=description
        
 
Store = Department(100, 'Food Shop', 45, 'Good Department')

Bob = Worker(56,'Bob','Lam',34,'1990-10-10','Red River Valley','USA', Store)

print(Bob.Department.name)
```

Output:

```
Food Shop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a worker to a department, you can do like this:

```
class Worker():
    def __init__(self,mark,name,department):
        self.mark=mark
        self.name=name
        self.department=department
        

class Department():
    def __init__(self,mark,name,maxNumberOfWorkers,description):
        self.mark=mark
        self.name=name
        self.maxNumberOfWorkers=maxNumberOfWorkers
        self.description=description


myDepartment = Department("DptMark","DptName", 100, "DptDesc")
myWorker = Worker("WorkerMark", "WorkerName", myDepartment)
print(myWorker.department.name) # DptName
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Composition. Think of it as real world. As your worker has a name, birth date and other attributes, then your worker also should HAVE A department where he works.
So you need make an object of Department inside the  Worker as follow.

```
class Worker(Identification):
    def __init__(self,mark,name, surname,personalNumber,dateOfBirth,placeOfBirth,countryOfBirth, department):
        #super().__init__(oznaka=oznaka)
        self.mark=mark
        self.name=name
        self.surname=surname
        self.personalnumber=personalnumber
        self.dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth
        self.placeOfBirth=placeOfBirth
        self.countryOfBirth=countryOfBirth
        self.department = department       # this will show which department he works in
```

Then when you create a Worker object, you simply assign a department to the worker too. But please note that the Department object needs to be created first :)

```
department = Department("A", "Mechanical", 100, "Mechanics grow here")
worker     = Worker("A", "John", "Smith", "28999273", "12-12-1990", "London", department)
```

Hope it's clear. Best of Luck.